# Is there a Windows equivalent to this unix-based command for running python unit tests?

Tags: python, powershell, environment-variables, pytest

I am trying to run python tests via pytest on a Windows machine. There is a shell script in this repository which contains a line of input to do so:

```
env $(cat ../env.example | xargs) pytest $@
```

As I understand it, this retrieves environment variables from env.example (located in the parent directory from where the tests live), builds them into an argument package `xargs`, and passes the arguments with the `pytest` command to the tests script.

This does not work on Windows, obviously. Namely because env and xargs are not native. I know that `set` works similarly to `env`. Aside from that, what would be the equivalent input to run these tests with the desired environment variables on my machine?

Comment: The proper Unix shell script would use `"$@"`. This is a common error. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) (Also, avoid the [useless `cat`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat))

Comment: Perhaps the best solution is to use python instead. What is in that env.example? This seems like a complicated way to run a command. As a note, `../env.example` references the current working directory, which wouldn't be the parent of the tests unless you've cd'd there.